# Show the series $\sum \frac{\log n}{n^2}$ converges by comparison

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that 
$$
\sum \frac{\log n}{n^2}
$$
Converges by the integral test
$$
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^2}dx=-\frac{\log x}{x}+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=c-\lim_{x\rightarrow}\frac{\log x}{x}=c
$$
But I was curious as to whether there was a clever way to show convergence by comparison.

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log n}{n^2}=-\zeta'(2) = \zeta(2)\left(\gamma+\log(2\pi)-12\log A\right)$$ where $A$ is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987623/convergence-of-frac-lnnn2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{\log n}{n^2}\le\frac{n^{1/2}}{n^2}=\frac1{n^{3/2}}$$

Because for **any** $\;\epsilon>0\;$, we have that for all but a finite number of values of 
$$\;n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;\;\log n<n^\epsilon$$

Comment: The "almost all values" is quite a bad phrasing: it could mean different things to different readers. "For all but a finite number" is much better; otherwise, one could consider the statement: "for almost all values of $n$, $n^2 \mathbb{1}_{n \rm is prime} = 0$" (which is true; the density of primes is going to $0$), but the series $\sum_n \frac{n^2 \mathbb{1}_{n \rm is prime}}{n^2}$ does not converge.

Comment: @ClementC. I agree with you, though "almost all" has, as far as I know, a pretty definite meaning in analysis in these things (as oposed as measure theory, say). Yet the OP probably hasn't yet studied that, so I shall change it. Thanks

Comment: @DonAntonio Just fyi I have seen it, I just haven't seen much intro calc, particularly series. Although I imagine people in the future reading this may not.

Comment: Isn't log n smaller than square root of n, for all n>0.

Comment: @jnyan Yes, it is.

Comment: @DonAntonio can you please tell how it can be rigorously proved that log n < $ n ^{ \epsilon } $ for all except a finite number of values of n.

Comment: For example, show (using L'Hospital's Rule or however) that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n^\epsilon}=0$$ for any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ ...

Answer (score 10):

For large $n$, $\log n < n^{\frac{1}{2}}$. And,

$$
\sum\frac{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}{n^{2}}=\sum\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}<\infty,
$$

by the $p$-test since $\frac{3}{2}>1$.

Therefore, the original series converges.

Answer (score 3):

An unusual proof may go through the following lines: since for any $n\geq 1$ we have
$$ \log(n) \leq H_n-\gamma-\frac{1}{2(n+1)} \tag{1}$$
it follows that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log n}{n^2}\color{red}{\leq} \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n^2}-\gamma\zeta(2)-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2n^2(n+1)}=\color{red}{\frac{6+24\,\zeta(3)-\pi^2(1+2\gamma)}{12}}\tag{2} $$

Answer (score 2):

We can also use the [Cauchy (Schlömilch) condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) and then the comparison test.
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{k}\mathrm{ln}(\mathrm{e}^{k})}{\mathrm{e}^{2k}}
= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{\mathrm{e}^{k}}
\end{equation}

We then compare this series with the convergent series $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^{3}}$$ and
thus our original series converges.